# Self Destruct Transaction

Tags: solidity, remix, selfdestruct, factory

how to make transaction like [THIS TRANSACTION](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x97f18c45f2bf1bca227561a306e468d9af49e642536a3d75674acd884c71cc48)

anyone can help me how to build it

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [`selfdestruct()`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/miscellaneous.html?highlight=selfdestruct#global-variables) function from solidity?

Comment: yes, can you tell me remix-ethereum script form this? and how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, you can't make a script that runs around exterminating other contracts. You can organize things so the contracts you create are willing to `selfdestruct` when you tell them to.

Here, a `Factory` contract deploys a series of 10 contracts that will `selfdestruct` if the `Factory` (and only the `Factory`) tells them to. There are verbose logs from both kinds of contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Factory {

    address[] public volatileContracts;
    event LogCreatedVolatileContract(address sender, address volatileContract);
    event LogKilledVolatileContract(address sender, address volatileContract);

    /**
     * If this were a real implementation, you would want access control over these functions.
     */

    function createVolatileContracts() public returns(bool success) {
        require(volatileContracts.length==0, "Ten at a time, please.");
        for(uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Volatile v = new Volatile();
            volatileContracts.push(address(v));
            emit LogCreatedVolatileContract(msg.sender, address(v));
        }
        return true;
    }

    function destroyVolatileContracts() public returns(bool success) {
        for(uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
            emit LogKilledVolatileContract(msg.sender, volatileContracts[i]);
            Volatile v = Volatile(volatileContracts[i]);
            v.kill();
        }
        volatileContracts.length=0;
        return true;
    }

}

contract Volatile {

    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    event LogSelfDestruction(address sender, address this, address owner, uint balance);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill() public onlyOwner {
        emit LogSelfDestruction(msg.sender, address(this), owner, address(this).balance);
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

It's just a scribble to give you some ideas. There are multiple non-trivial concerns you would to address before thinking about using it. No warranty.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract exampleContract {

    event Debug(bool destroyed); // Create an event to let web3 know that contract is destroyed

    constructor () public {

    // I've set this function internal which means you can only call this function from another function.
    // You can set it to public but I'd recommend you to create a modifier for owner and use it instead.
    function _destroyContract() internal {
        emit Debug(true); // call event
        // this - is the current contract address
        selfdestruct(this); // selfDestruct contract
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!